# Reset all changes in branch against main

Tags: git

Let's say I have a feature branch called `feat` with 3 changes:

```
(feat) HEAD -> c1 -> c2 -> c3
```

`c1` added a file called `c1.txt` to the root, `c2` added a file called `c2.txt` to the root, and so on.

My goal is to have all changes from the `feat` branch unstaged in `main`. That is, I want `c1.txt`, `c2.txt` and `c3.txt` red in my `main` branch.

How can I make this happen?

For context, this is just a basic example. In reality I have a branch with dozens of changes spanned across multiple months. There are even some merges from main in there. So it is next to impossible to figure out all commits I need to reset. I just want to essentially recreate the changes from scratch on main and work off of that so I can start from a fresh slate.

The following seemed to work for me in this simple example:

```
(feat) git reset main
(feat) git co main
```

But not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: You already commit the changes in your feat branch?

Comment: @MaikLowrey yes

Comment: And cherry picking is an option for you?

Comment: This may work for the basic example above but it doesn't seem scalable if the branch has hundreds of commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout to your main branch and cherry pick the last commits to your main branch. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick